# RSpec unable to find link on button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm getting the following RSpec error after trying to complete Chapter 5 Exercise 3 of Hartl's rails tutorial:

```
1) Static pages should have the right links on the layout
 Failure/Error: click_link "Sign up now!"
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find link "Sign up now!"
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

It seems to be unable to find the sign up now link on the button.

Here is the relevant section from my spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb file:

```
it "should have the right links on the layout" do
    visit root_path
    click_link "About"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About Us'))
    click_link "Help"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Help'))
    click_link "Contact"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Contact'))
    click_link "Sign up now!"
    expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sign Up'))
    click_link "Home"
    expect(page).to have_content('Sample')
    click_link "sample app"
    expect(page).to have_content('Sample')
end
```

It's asking if the page on clicking the sign up link has the page title "Sign Up." But it can't even find the "Sign up now!" link, as the error above shows. Here's the home page at app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb as well, to show that it does indeed have the "Sign Up Now!" link (as a button, but i have tried click_button to no success as well):

```
 <div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

<h2>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</h2>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path , class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

So I'm not sure why it can't find that "Sign up now!" link when it is clearly formatted that way. When I run rails server locally, it clearly has that link. Thanks for any guidance.

Here's the signup page, at app/views/users/new.html.erb, just to cover my bases. As you can see, it does make the page title 'Sign Up':

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign Up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/users/new.html.erb</p>
```

Finally, here are my routes, also to cover my bases. As you can see, it does route to users new:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
  root 'static_pages#home'
  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', via: 'get'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
  match '/signup', to: 'users#new', via: 'get'
  .
  .
  .
end
```

In case it might be a gemfile error, here's my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'

end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you click a link, Capybara, the headless browser, navigates to that page. So by the time you get to clicking `Sign up now!` in your tests, your headless browser is at the Contact page, not the Home page.

Specifying `visit root_path` before you try to click "Sign up now!" link should work.

You could alternatively insert `click_link 'Home'` before trying to click "Sign up now!".

Another, perhaps better-structured, solution would be to have a test for each link:

```
describe "layout" do

    before(:each) do
        visit root_path
    end

    it "should have About link" do
        click_link 'About'
        expect(page).to have_title(full_title('About Us'))
    end

    it "should have Help link" do
        click_link 'Help'
        expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Help'))
    end

    it "should have Sign Up link" do
        click_link "Sign up now!"
        expect(page).to have_title(full_title('Sign Up'))
    end


    (...)

end
```

Good luck!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much for the wonderfully clear explanation as to the problem, as well as the better structured response!